# How to get the median of a column based on another column value using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I get the median  of `ConvertedComp` column for all `Gender = 'Woman'` from this Pandas dataframe (It only shows 'Man' because I'm only showing `df.head(10)`):

|  | ConvertedComp | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 61000.0 | Man |
| 1 | 95179.0 | Man |
| 2 | 90000.0 | Man |
| 3 | 455452.0 | Man |
| 4 | 65277.0 | Man |
| 5 | 31140.0 | Man |
| 6 | 41244.0 | Man |
| 7 | 103000.0 | Man |
| 8 | 69000.0 | Man |
| 9 | 26388.0 | Man |

Comment: Filter for woman and calculate the median for that column: `df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'Woman'], ['ConvertedComp']].median()` or `df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'Woman'], 'ConvertedComp'].median()`

Answer (score 1):

group by gender and return the median of convertedcomp -

```
In [1]:
df.groupby('gender')['convertedcomp'].median()

Out [1]:
gender
man      910
woman     42
Name: convertedcomp, dtype: int64

#this worked in the notebook, not sure the difference in syntax between the two answers, someone might be able to shine some light on that
In [2]:
data = {'convertedcomp': [61, 951, 910, 30, 42, 899], 'gender': ['man', 'man', 'man', 'woman', 'woman', 'woman']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df.groupby('gender').median('convertedcomp')

Out [2]:
    convertedcomp
gender  
man     910
woman   42
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get the following error `df.groupby('Gender').median('ConvertedComp')

TypeError: median() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` any ideas?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez the syntax is wrong in this answer. The following will work: `df.groupby('gender')['convertedcomp'].median()`

Comment: @DavidErickson BOOOOMBASTIC!

Comment: @robert_553z8 kindly fix your syntax :)

Comment: @DavidErickson: please go ahead and post the correct syntax as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
df[df['Gender']=='Woman']['ConvertedComp'].median()